# Three.js throws error for scene object and float32array in IE9

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

When trying to use CanvasRenderer to draw 3D object to make it compatible in IE9 I am getting error float32array error, scene error.

My code is here -

```
            var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); // Fallback to canvas renderer, if necessary.
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 
            var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); 
            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 20, 20); 
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000FF }); 
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 
            scene.add(cube); 

            camera.position.z = 50; 

            var render = function () {
            cube.rotation.x += 0.01; 
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(render); 
            };

            render(); // Start the rendering of the animation frames.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4452 help you?

Comment: No. I have already tried with typedarray.js but its not working.

Comment: Finally its working in IE9. Thanks.

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue and adding typedarray didn't work for me. It seems like it initially didn't work for you either.

Would you care to share how you got this working, so that the rest of don't have to lose as much hair? ;-)

Comment: Can you post the code here (just header portion)? @Ricebandit